# How to code to draw y1 and y2 axis using coreplot in ios 8?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-plot

Am using core plot for drawing line  graph.i want two y axis with different interval.

for x y axis i used following code.

```
  #pragma mark - Chart behavior
    -(void)initPlotForDancis {
        [self configureHostDancis];
        [self configureGraphDancis];
        [self configurePlotsDancis];
        [self configureAxesDancis];
    }

    -(void)configureHostDancis {
        self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0, dancisView.frame.size.width, dancisView.frame.size.height-150)];
        self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
        [dancisView addSubview:self.hostView];
    }

    -(void)configureGraphDancis {
        // 1 - Create the graph
        CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
        self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
        // 2 - Set graph title
        NSString *title = @"Dancis Graph";
        graph.title = title;
        // 3 - Create and set text style
        CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
        titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
        graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
        graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
        graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);
        // 4 - Set padding for plot area
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:30.0f];
        [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:30.0f];
        // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    }

    -(void)configurePlotsDancis {
        // 1 - Get graph and plot space
        CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        // 2 - Create the three plots
        CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
        aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
        aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
        CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
        [graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
        CPTScatterPlot *googPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
        googPlot.dataSource = self;
        googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
        CPTColor *googColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
        [graph addPlot:googPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
        CPTScatterPlot *msftPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
        msftPlot.dataSource = self;
        msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
        CPTColor *msftColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
        [graph addPlot:msftPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
        // 3 - Set up plot space
        [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aaplPlot, googPlot, msftPlot, nil]];
        CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
        [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
        plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
        CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
        [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
        plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
        // 4 - Create styles and symbols
        CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplLineStyle = [aaplPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        aaplLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
        aaplLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
        aaplPlot.dataLineStyle = aaplLineStyle;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *aaplSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        aaplSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = aaplColor;
        CPTPlotSymbol *aaplSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
        aaplSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:aaplColor];
        aaplSymbol.lineStyle = aaplSymbolLineStyle;
        aaplSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
        aaplPlot.plotSymbol = aaplSymbol;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *googLineStyle = [googPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        googLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
        googLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
        googPlot.dataLineStyle = googLineStyle;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *googSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        googSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = googColor;
        CPTPlotSymbol *googSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol starPlotSymbol];
        googSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:googColor];
        googSymbol.lineStyle = googSymbolLineStyle;
        googSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
        googPlot.plotSymbol = googSymbol;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *msftLineStyle = [msftPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
        msftLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
        msftLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
        msftPlot.dataLineStyle = msftLineStyle;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *msftSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        msftSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = msftColor;
        CPTPlotSymbol *msftSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol diamondPlotSymbol];
        msftSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:msftColor];
        msftSymbol.lineStyle = msftSymbolLineStyle;
        msftSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
        msftPlot.plotSymbol = msftSymbol;

    //   // plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0)
    //                                                length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(10)];
    //    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0)
    //                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(2000)];
    //   
    }

    -(void)configureAxesDancis {
        // 1 - Create styles
        CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
        axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
        axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
        axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
        axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
        tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
        // 2 - Get axis set
        CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
        // 3 - Configure x-axis
        CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
        x.title = @"Age In Days";
        x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
        x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
        x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
        x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
        x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
        x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
        x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
        x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;







        CGFloat dateCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
        NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
        NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
        NSInteger i = 0;
        for (NSString *date in [[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth]) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
            CGFloat location = i++;
            label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
            label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
            if (label) {
                [xLabels addObject:label];
                [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
            }
        }
        x.axisLabels = xLabels;
        x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;



        // 4 - Configure y-axis
        CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
        y.title = @"Width";
        y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
        y.titleOffset = 10.0f;
        y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
        y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
        y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
        y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
        y.labelOffset = -10.0f;
        y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
        y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
        y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
        y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
        NSInteger majorIncrement = 100;
        NSInteger minorIncrement = 50;
        CGFloat yMax = 50000.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
        NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
        NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
        NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
            NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
            if (mod == 0) {
                CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
                NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
                label.tickLocation = location;
                label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
                if (label) {
                    [yLabels addObject:label];
                }
                [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
            } else {
                [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
            }
        }
        y.axisLabels = yLabels;
        y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
        y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;

    }
```

how to draw y2 axis.using core plot library. how to draw line graph with two i.e. y1 and y2 axis.y1 start 500.1000,1500,..... and y2 start 10,20,30,40,..... and x axis start 20,25,30,35,40,......

Comment: Hi. I just want to create a graph using corepolt in ios8. while adding headers i am getting errors can you please suggest any links or tutorials. I checked raywenderlich tutorial but its not for ios8. can you please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another plot space for the second y-axis. Make the `xRange` the same as the first plot space. The *Plot Gallery* example app has several demos for this. The "Plot Space Demo" creates several plot spaces with different settings and assigns an axis to each one. The "Axis Demo" shows how to set up a second y-axis.

Comment: I have added second plotspace   CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2 = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
    [graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
but in y2 axis label and tic r not displayed.why tic not displayed.

Comment: issues solve.am getting hard to labeling.i want y1 start 500.1000,1500,..... and y2 start 10,20,30,40,..... and x axis start 20,25,30,35,40,......how to code to define min max and interval in that

Comment: Plot ranges have a starting location and length (max - min). You are creating your own tick locations and labels; you can put them where ever you want. The `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval` labeling policy (the default) will automatically place ticks and labels at fixed intervals along the axis, separated by the `majorIntervalLength`.

Comment: when i declare majorIntervalLength=5 then minarIntervalLength=?

Comment: can u give some example.

Comment: thanks sir!!i can 0,5,10,15 .but now tic distance is more .how to decrease tic distance .

Comment: There are lots of samples in the *Plot Gallery* example app. Increase the length of the plot range to reduce the space between ticks.

Comment: Thank you sir i got my answer.

Comment: Hello sir,i am having three axis  y1 and y2 and x is common. now i can draw a line using CPTScatterPlotFieldX and CPTScatterPlotFieldy but how to code to draw line between x and y2 .